# How to navigate one project to another in same same solution?

Tags: windows, winforms

I have two projects in my solution explorer one is windows 8.1 app and another one is windows form,when i click windows 8.1 button i want to navigate windows form project and when i click button in windows form project i want to navigate windows 8.1, please any one help me to solve this problem

thanks advance,
Kartik.

Comment: Where will be those buttons? I mean in which project?

Comment: i have two project in same solution , two project have two login buttons 1)Windowsform login 2)windows8.1 login, when i click Windowsform login i want to open Windowsform project, when i click windows8.1 login i want to open windows 8.1 project.